R script says a column doesn't exist despite the spelling being correct and it recognizing all other columns
I'm trying to get summary stats of a linelist csv and so far it'll read every column except for one and I cannot figure out why. It's spelled correctly in the code and it's no different from the other columns but every time i try to run "get_summary_stats" it gives me an error message that this column doesn't exist

I'm just trying to get the summary stats of the linelist. It will read all the other columns except for this one. I've tried different configurations with the parenthesis and different commas and things but it still won't read. Should I try a different order of column titles?


Can you edit your question to include the output of running dput(head(cirrhosis_linelist))? Also, it would be better if you could paste the text into the question as text instead of as pictures.

You should not post code as an image because...

(For future questions, please put the code and errors in as text, and share some example data / output as text. This would have made the problem self-evident.)
In your picture of the View window, note that the values in Cirrhosis_deaths are left-aligned, suggesting they were read in as text and not as numbers. Presumably some value in that column was non-numeric.
I see that rstatix::get_summary_stats() first selects the numeric columns:
https://github.com/kassambara/rstatix/blob/master/R/get_summary_stats.R
data <- data %>% select_numeric_columns()

As such, your column won't be available to the rest of the function, despite you seeing it existing. I expect this could be resolved with
cirrhosis_linelist$Cirrhosis_deaths = as.numeric(cirrhosis_linelist$Cirrhosis_deaths)

...but you should look closely at the data that is loaded, since there is probably something in that column that made read.csv presume that column was text and not numeric.
